# What's the difference between "that will be $200" and "that would be $200"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

When you are negotiating prices with your customer, you might say "that's $200," "that'll be $200," or "that would be $200." Are there any differences among them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*That **is** $200* means the current price is $200.  You could tell this to someone who has not expressed any interest in purchasing the item, or you could use it with someone who is actually buying it.

*That **will be** $200* is only used when the person has bought or at least is getting ready to buy the item, and needs to know the price.

*That **would be** $200* is somewhere between the other two - slightly implying that the person you're talking to might buy the item, but not nearly as decisive as *will be*.

Comment: Well, Daniel provided no references.  So: What if he just made it up?

Comment: @GEdgar that's what voting it for, essentially, and rep. Welcome to Stack Exchange.

Comment: Although that's not to say references wouldn't be nice, but for something as trivial as this, we have enough native speakers here to vote it up without.

Comment: Also regardless of a reference, this is how the English language is understood in the United States.  The understood meaning of what @Daniel said is exactly correct.